# Swift: Pause an animation that is moving along a path?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

I have an animation of a bubble, like so:

```
func bubblePoint(_ value: CGFloat, midX: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    let startY: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    let endY: CGFloat = -100

    let rangeX: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.1

    let y = startY + (endY - startY) * value
    let x = sin(value * 4 * .pi) * rangeX * (0.1 + value * 0.9) + midX * UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    let point = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    return point
}

func bubblePath(midX: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: bubblePoint(0, midX: midX))
    for value in stride(from: CGFloat(0.01), through: 1, by: 0.01) {
        path.addLine(to: bubblePoint(value, midX: midX))
    }
    return path
}

func createAnimation(midX: CGFloat, duration: CFTimeInterval) -> CAKeyframeAnimation {
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.path = bubblePath(midX: midX).cgPath
    animation.duration = duration
    animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    return animation
}

func createBubble(midX: CGFloat, duration: CFTimeInterval) -> (UIImageView, CAKeyframeAnimation) {
    return (
        view: UIImageView().then {
            $0.image = image
        },
        animation: createAnimation(midX: midX, duration: duration)
    )
}

let bubbles = createBubble(midX: 100,    duration: 11, )
bubble.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

I want to pause the bubble when the user goes to another screen (and then resume the animation when the user comes back). I have looked into a solution like [this](https://gist.github.com/nazywamsiepawel/e462193f299187d0fc8e), but I would have no idea how to do this with an animation that uses a path like mine. Is it practical to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main ways to pause (freeze) an animation. One is to set the layer `speed` to zero. The other is to wrap the animation in a UIViewPropertyAnimator and pause the animator (you can do this even with a keyframe animation).

Notice, however, that when "user goes to another screen" the animation may be removed entirely. You may thus need to store info about where in the animation we were and start from there when your view controller comes back on screen.